# How do I insert Windows form data in 2 different tables?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have created 2 tables `student and course`. the fields in the

student table are    `(student_id, student_name,.....).` The fields in the

course table are `(course_id, student_id,......)`. The Windows form to fill out the `student and course` table is the same.
I am able to insert the student data in the student table.

Now, my question is how do I fill the student_id in the course table, since i don't know the student_id)?

So far i am able to insert the student and course data separately, leaving the student_id in the course table empty.

```
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_student (student_name, student_address, student_gender,student_dob,student_phone)" & _
                "VALUES (" & _
                "'" & name & "'," & _
                "'" & address & "'," & _
                "'" & gender & "'," & _
                "'" & dob & "'," & _
                "'" & phone & "'," & _
                "'" & phone & "' )"
Dim query1 As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_course (student_id, course_name)" & _
                "VALUES (" & _
                "'" & student_id & "'," & _
                "'" & cname & "' )"
```

I am not sure what to fill in the student_id of the 2nd query. The student_id in the first table is an auto increment field.

Comment: I have edited the question above to put my code in...

Comment: select SCOPE_IDENTITY() after the first insert. and please! use parameters in your statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first INSERT you can add the OUTPUT-Clause to get the Student_id for the current INSERT back without an extra request. You only have to handle the Output.

```
INSERT INTO ....
OUTPUT inserted.student_id
VALUES (...);
```

If the INSERT fails due to key violation SQL-Server gives an empty resultset back.

If you use SCOPE_IDENTITY() it could be that you get the ID from an earlier inserted Student if an insert Fails. So I would recommend using OUTPUT

Comment: I used the above code you said... but now how do i get the student_id to be displayed using a message box or make the use of the student_id?

Comment: Did you retrieve the value for student_id from SQL-Server? This value has to be the input for your second query.    I'm not a VB.NET guy and so can't say how to code a messagebox or so. In VBA I would open a Recordset to get the resultset from SQL-Server and process the first row